# json-mode hook not being run

Tags: hooks, json

I have

```
(add-hook 'json-mode 'flymake-json-load)
```

in my .emacs file, but it has no effect. I have to do `M-x flymake-json-load` whenever I visit a `.json` file. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 3):

`add-hook` does not take a mode symbol as its first parameter; it takes a symbol for a hook variable.

Replace `'json-mode` with `'json-mode-hook` and you'll be all set.

Note the differences between the symbols. One is a variable used to store a list of functions to run when entering `json-mode`:

> json-mode-hook is a variable defined in ‘json-mode.el’.
>
> Documentation: Hook run after entering JSON mode.

and the other is a function used to enter `json-mode`.

> json-mode is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
>   ‘json-mode.el’.
>
> Parent mode: ‘javascript-mode’.
>
> Major mode for editing JSON files

Comment: As a general guideline, the name of the hook for a mode is usually `<hook mode name>-hook`... For example, the hook for `org-mode` is called `org-mode-hook`, and the hook for `c-mode` is `c-mode-hook`. (And so on.)

Comment: Indeed most modes are defined using macros which *enforce* this naming scheme (and those which do not use the macros invariably adhere strictly to the same rules).